# docker cron symfony not reading .env file

Tags: docker, cron

I have a docker container that installs cron, and for now i manually start the service in the container as root. The cron runs the tasks fine but it's not reading the .env file in the symfony root.

First i tried:

```
RUN echo "* * * * * www-data php /usr/share/nginx/html/api/bin/console notifications:manual:process >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1" >> /etc/crontab
```

And then i tried:

```
RUN echo "* * * * * www-data . /usr/share/nginx/html/api/.env && php /usr/share/nginx/html/api/bin/console notifications:manual:process >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1" >> /etc/crontab
```

I'm getting this in the cron log:

```
In EnvVarProcessor.php line 131:
                                              
  Environment variable not found: "DB_NAME".
```

The .env file exists, and it has DB_NAME in there, so i don't know what is going on, i use this same approach with a laravel system and it reads the .env no problem.